# MongoDB - Sort by custom priority

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I'm currently working on a doctor directory web app with mongoose. It lists the doctors from the database including their name, specialty, rating, and location.

When a doctor is selected, it takes you to a detail page containing their info. However, here's the part that I'm stuck at. Like many other websites, there is always a section regarding related/similar results. In this case, there will be a section with similar doctors. The priority that I wanted them to be listed in:

1. Specialty is equal to current result's specialty
2. Location is equal to current result's location

That's basically it. I know how to query for doctors with the same specialty and location as the current result, but the .sort() function in mongoose seems like it is limited to sorting with ascending and descending order, which would not work in this case. How would I go about sort with this custom priority?

EDIT:

Example -

```
   {name: "Bill", specialty: "Internal Medicine", location: "San Francisco"...}
   {name: "Joe", specialty: "Cardiology", location: "San Francisco"...}
   {name: "Tom", specialty: "Internal Medicine", location: "San Jose"...}
   {name: "Jess", specialty: "Cardiology", location: "San Jose"...}
```

So if we are on Bill's details page, the related results should be in this order: Tom, Joe, then Jess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You basically want to "rank/sort" on calculated values. You use [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for this to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the calculation result as a new field, then you [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on that new "calculated" value. Ideally you could "store" the calculation as you create data. But your question is unclear as to your actual case. Please elaborate with sample data and expected results.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for getting back to me. I've added sample data above.

Comment: But you do not really explain your "inputs". I presume "current result" is meant to be something like `"Cardiology"` and `"San Jose"`. In which you use "logical" aggregation operators such as [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) within a [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to return a "numeric" value on which you "sort". There's a whole bundle of links there. I suggest you actually go and look at them and see what the operators do.